# create A Form in jquery (mostly) [contactable] ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I just need a little help fomr someone to help explain the HTML within this JQ plugin.

plugin and demo are here: [plugin](http://anygoogle.com/contactable/jquery.contactable.js) & [Demo](http://theodin.co.uk/blog/ajax/contactable-jquery-plugin.html/)

its called   **"Contactable"**

the person/people made a pop-out form using javascript, most of the html is in the js and *one*

```
   < div >
```

is used to call the form on a html file. 
Essentually it allows for a non invasive form to be placed on to a page.

**can anyone help explain the html part of the coding** thanks

Comment: I thought the website covered it pretty well. What exactly were you unclear about?

Comment: If you have a doubt in some part of the code then somw one will try to explore that.

Answer (score 2):

What do you need explaining? The jQuery inserts the following HTML into the element matched by the selector (from the demo page you linked to):

```
<div id="contactable_inner" style="margin-left: 377px; "></div>
<form id="contactForm" method="" action="" style="margin-left: -10px; ">
    <div id="loading"></div>
    <div id="callback"></div>
    <div class="holder">
        <p>
            <label for="name">Name<span class="red"> * </span></label><br>
            <input id="name" class="contact" name="name">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">Email <span class="red"> * </span></label><br>
            <input id="email" class="contact" name="email">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="message">Message <span class="red"> * </span></label><br>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" class="message" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="SEND">
        </p>
        <p class="disclaimer">
            Please feel free to get in touch, we value your feedback
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

It does so with the following long line. `this` will be a reference to whatever element was matched by the selector (if there were several, the form is inserted into each):

```
$(this).html('<div id="contactable_inner"></div><form id="contactForm" method="" action=""><div id="loading"></div><div id="callback"></div><div class="holder"><p><label for="name">'+options.name+'<span class="red"> * </span></label><br /><input id="name" class="contact" name="name"/></p><p><label for="email">'+options.email+' <span class="red"> * </span></label><br /><input id="email" class="contact" name="email" /></p><p><label for="message">'+options.message+' <span class="red"> * </span></label><br /><textarea id="message" name="message" class="message" rows="4" cols="30" ></textarea></p><p><input class="submit" type="submit" value="'+options.submit+'"/></p><p class="disclaimer">'+options.disclaimer+'</p></div></form>');
```

Comment: I think part of your comment got cut off, might want to post it again :) (If it was code, put it in backtick characters).

Comment: so if i made a **div** within a **div** through CSS and used the:

*$(this).html()* line, then placed the first div in my html file.. all the contents would be placed in side right?

**example**
`$(this).html()` = #one #two + contents  

<div id="one"> *html for the JS would be placed here* </div>
that should work right?

Do i need to add anything before : `$(this).html()` 

or

i can simply open a blank JS file and type this then my html within then it will call up ? (obviously i'v linked the files)

Comment: No, because `this` won't refer to what you want it to. You really need to properly learn the basics of JavaScript. Play around with what you're trying to do and post new questions on SO when you get stuck. As long as you show that you've made an effort, people will be happy to help.